# KVM guest storage difference with NBD and NFS

Tags: debian, kvm-virtualization, nfs

I am setting up my own little private cloud for my own use maybe for a project or to. I am using linux kvm on debian 6. I have 3 servers 2 of them for compute nodes and 1 storage node. I would I have already installed kvm made a few test machines got my networking setup. I have 2 nics on each server 1 nic is for web traffic other nic is for network traffic.

My first Idea was to use NFS for storing the guest machines which can range in size, maybe 8gb maybe 100gb, it just depends. I was doing have heard of nbd before seems like it could work but I dont know what the performance differences are and if it will effect my enviroment, nfs looks like it will be easier to use.

Comment: I have never heard of NBD until now, and am not convinced of it's superiority over [tag:iscsi] (the *other* network block serving technology and by *far* more common).

Comment: @sysadmin1138 I have no idea why i did not think about using iscsi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NFS is pretty easy, and NFS4 makes things even better if you can leverage that. It's definitely easier than block-devices like NBD or iSCSI.

That said, block-devices should provide a bit of an edge over file-backed stores, though that's less true with NFS4 than it was with NFS3. Of the block-devices, I'd definitely with with iSCSI versus NBD because the toolchain and code-paths are much deeper and better tested, not to mention getting help with it is a lot easier as a result.

Comment: the issue i see with using iSCSI is that i cant mount the easily share the same folders with both servers, not to say I will have two different servers run the same vm, More that i am gonig to have to manage more mount points.

Comment: @WojonsTech Those are very valid points, and one of the reasons that NFS4 is actually a very good option. Doing it with iSCSI requires a clustered filesystem like GFS and that's the opposite of easy to set up.

Comment: do you know of anyway that I will also be able to use something like lvm other then for the nfs paration its self.

Comment: @WojonsTech An NFS share is just a normal mount point, so LVM is perfectly doable for both the shared volume and the root of the NFS server itself.

Comment: You have been a great help thank you very much for your time.